# How do I select these children divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert the ids of each of these divs so it output `11 25 78`.

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="section-11">Some content</div>
  <div id="section-25">Some content</div>
  <div id="section-78">Some content</div>
</div>
```

I've already selected `main` and I'm trying to use `children` but it's not working. Not sure why.

```
$('#main').children().each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/mfgXG/

Are you forgetting to run after on ready?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#main div').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id').replace(/section-/, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work at least in FF. Have a look there [at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/GCemL/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are more nested `div` elements there, i.e. those "section" elements are not direct children of the main panel?

In such case, have such selector:

```
$('#main div[id^="section-"]').each(function(){
```

To find all matching elements.